# "Plenty" with "much/easy/long/etc."

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, adverbs

I'm sure I'm on the right track of understanding how the adverb "**plenty**" works with other words but from example such as "*She had plenty more work to do*" I'm assuming we can use "**plenty**" with pretty much anything to '*emphasize the degree of something*'. Thus arises the question, "*In which case is it natural to use 'plenty' and in which not?*"

- There's plenty much information about it on the net.
- The job was done plenty easy/easily today.
- It took you plenty long to get here.

What do you think friends?

Comment: Uses of "plenty" as an adverb is something I find to be not just dialectical, but definitely outside of my dialect ("standard" American English).  I understand "plenty much" as unidiomatic and "plenty long" as idiomatic, but neither one is a usage I would ever use.

Comment: _plenty **more** information_, not _plenty much information_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the entry for **plenty** in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plenty), it does say that **plenty** can be used as an adverb, but most of the example sentences they provide sound like the sort of things that a scriptwriter would give to a Mexican character to make them sound foreign.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plenty%20fast%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cplenty%20fast%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplenty%20fast%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplenty%20fast%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that **plenty fast** is not very widely used, and it is more common in American writing than in British writing. Many of the instances are in fictional native american dialogue

> "That is good," answered Night Bear. "Where did you learn the tongue?" "Me learn tongue plenty fast by pony fort," the man said. [Seven arrows](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=MFk1nZUWbDIC&q=%22plenty%20fast%22&dq=%22plenty%20fast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZx5u9lfLYAhVCbbwKHYdACg04MhDoAQhBMAU)

... or period writing where the characters are poorly educated non-indigenous people.

> "In fact, he's plenty fast enough to have killed Johnny and all the others in a fair fight.” [Wrath of the Mountain Man](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=3bYsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT72&dq=%22plenty%20fast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaieKWkPLYAhUHy7wKHXgPBpkQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22plenty%20fast%22&f=false)

There are also several pieces of technical writing in a demotic style, aimed at consumers: reviews of computers, SLR cameras etc.

> Fast Ethernet networks are plenty fast for a home network. But in case you're an extreme user, or building a high-speed office network, there is the next step up in speed, called Gigabit Ethernet. Gigabit Ethernet moves at a scorching 1000Mbps. [Speed: unerstanding and installing home networks](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=cwxZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22plenty%20fast%22&dq=%22plenty%20fast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZx5u9lfLYAhVCbbwKHYdACg04MhDoAQgyMAI)

The [Oxford Guide to English Grammar](https://www.uop.edu.jo/download/research/members/oxford_guide_to_english_grammar.pdf) contains several references to the use of plenty as a quantifier, but none whatsoever to the adverb form.

> We have plenty of money. 
>   I have eaten plenty, thank you.

Given the lack of adequate explanation of the rules and reliable examples for using the adverbal form, I would recommend avoiding this form completely, apart from with **more**. As a native British English speaker, I would never consider using the sentences that you have suggested. This is what I would say:

> There's plenty **of** information about it on the net.
>   The job was done **very** easy/easily today.
>   It took you long **enough** to get here.

The first sentence can use the pronoun form  (plenty of...): for the other two, plenty doesn't really work at all.

Comment: Thanks JavaLatte but I was hoping a decent explanation concerning "plenty" as an adverb. Not that I disrespect or not love your wonderful answers and explanations, but this isn't exactly what I wanted to hear unless you think my English is that bad that I cannot find a different approach, or solution to saying what I want to say, or paraphrase it in order not to include "plenty" as an adverb. :-)

Comment: To me, all of the "plenty"+adjective examples (plenty much, plenty easy, plenty long) sound like Tonto, the American Indian sidekick of the Lone Ranger. I think that "plenty of"+plural noun or "plenty of"+uncountable noun sound like living English (plenty of times, plenty of people, plenty of water, plenty of room) and as a noun "plenty" has a sort of nostalgic quality ("We came here expecting great plenty.")

Comment: (As I re-read, I suppose that the examples I called "living English" also sound slightly informal.)

Comment: @SovereignSun: I am sorry that my answer doesn't meet with your approval. As I made clear in my answer, I adapted your sentences to show how to use **plenty** where possible, and to provide alternatives where it definitely won't work.The fact remains that your suggestions don't sound natural to me as a Brfitish English speaker and there is a dearth of reliable reference material. In the absence of such material, I am not willing to simply make something up. Maybe such sentences are more widely used in the US, and not just by Tonto. I hope that somebody else can shed some light on this for you.

Comment: I don't have any problem with, _"It took you plenty long to get here,"_ but even that one sounds "plenty colloquial." (I don't picture Tonto, but there are a few country friends in Nebraska that come to mind.) I'd not be very likely to use it myself.

Answer (score 2):

*Plenty* is used as an adverb in American English, but not arbitrarily so, and usually not merely to add emphasis. I would honestly never think to use it in the examples you have suggested.

A search on "plenty" followed by another adverb in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) returns these frequency results at the top:

> ```
>   CONTEXT FREQ
> ```
>
> 1. PLENTY MORE    294
> 2. PLENTY BIG 28
> 3. PLENTY FAST    28
> 4. PLENTY GOOD    27
> 5. PLENTY ENOUGH  21
> 6. PLENTY ELSE    20
> 7. PLENTY LONG    19
> 8. PLENTY THERE   11
> 9. PLENTY HERE    11
> 10. PLENTY HARD    8
> 11. PLENTY HIGH    7
> 12. PLENTY LOUD    7
> 13. PLENTY NOW 7
> 14. PLENTY DEEP    7
> 15. PLENTY ELSEWHERE   6
> 16. PLENTY OUT 6
> 17. PLENTY IN  6
> 18. PLENTY RIGHT   6
> 19. PLENTY QUICK   5
> 20. PLENTY BAD 5
> 21. PLENTY ALREADY 5

With adjectives, the top results are

> 1. PLENTY TOUGH   30
> 2. PLENTY BIG 19
> 3. PLENTY WARM    19
> 4. PLENTY STRONG  17
> 5. PLENTY GOOD    15
> 6. PLENTY HOT 14
> 7. PLENTY BUSY    13
> 8. PLENTY BRIGHT  13
> 9. PLENTY ACCURATE    11
> 10. PLENTY SMART   11
> 11. PLENTY DURABLE 9
> 12. PLENTY OLD 9
> 13. PLENTY STURDY  7
> 14. PLENTY LARGE   6
> 15. PLENTY MAD 6
> 16. PLENTY HAPPY   5
> 17. PLENTY CAPABLE 5
> 18. PLENTY OTHER   5
> 19. PLENTY RICH    5
> 20. PLENTY ROOMY   5

As you can see, *plenty more* is the most common formulation by a full order of magnitude. It is found in common expressions like *[plenty more where that came from](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-plenty-more-where-sb-sth-came-from)* and *there's plenty more ahead* (or other expressions of something forthcoming or anticipated), so not only will you encounter it more often, but it is more likely to be accepted than others.

There are instances of *plenty long* in a variety of sources, whereas *plenty easy* occurs only once, in spoken dialog in fiction, and *plenty much* does not appear at all. This maps to my own instinct; I can't think of any native speakers of American English I know who would say *There's plenty much information about it on the net.* To say there is an abundance of information,

> There's plenty of information about it on the net

would be fine in speech, and

> There is much information about it on the net

would be fine in writing, and to add emphasis I would likely use different constructions entirely, like *there's a whole lot of information* or *there is a great deal of information*.

In cases like most of the appearances of *plenty long*, *plenty* is not an intensifer. Rather it communicates that something is adequately or satisfactorily long, though not as explicitly as saying *long enough*. Indeed, the [AHD one-word definition](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=plenty) of adverbial *plenty* is

> Sufficiently.

Comment: Well, if so is the way things go looks like JavaLatte is perfectly right and thus her answer deserves a +1, yours too.